# getElementsByTagName - failing inconsistently

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, getelementsbytagname

I am using a Java application to read an XML file and process it. The application works in the majority of cases but not in some. I have an XML doc with a list of items. The app reads the doc and compiles a list of said items as follows:

NodeList responseItemNodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns:myElement")

Sometimes a list is compiled and sometimes not. I have looked at different XML docs, ones that work and ones that don't and to me, they seem identical (apart from data).

Can anyone suggest why this is occasionally failing?

EDIT: I have tried Xpath and the issue still happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `getElementsByTagName` that takes a namespace parameter and a local name instead of using the prefix qualified name.  Since your current code sometimes works it is probably because you are not setting `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the `DocumentBuilderFactory`.

Comment: I know for certain the namespace will e 'ns' (it is ns in the case that works and fails). Knowing this, won't getElementsByTagName suffice?

Comment: @heyya99 - For namespace qualified XML documents you should use the XML APIs that include a namespace.  Otherwise you are going to get unpredicable fragile results.

Comment: Your suggestion seems like best practice, in case the namespace changes but do you think it'd solve my issue?

Comment: @heyya99 - It is important to note that there is a difference between the namespace prefix (the `ns` portion of `ns:foo`) and the namespace that it corresponds to `(the `http://www.example.com/blah` of `xmlns:ns="http://www.example.com/blah"`.  The namespace hopefully doesn't change in your use case, but the prefix may.  Using the namespace methods should definitely fix your issue.

Comment: I have 2 example xml docs - one that is parseable and and one that is not. Both have the following namespace: <ns:myResponse xmlns:ns="ht tp://Hello.com/xml">. If I know in this particular case that the namespace is the same, I can't see how your suggestion makes a difference. Deployment of my app is non-trivial and takes time so I need to be sure a difference will be made.

Comment: @heyya99 - If the DOM is namespace aware then you should be using the namespace aware APIs.  Since your current approach is yielding inconsistent results it seems worth a try.  Using the namespace aware methods will also protect you if someone changes the prefix.  Any reason you don't want to use the namespace aware methods?

Comment: I am happy to use them but I deployments are non-trivial and I need to ensure that a change I make will make a difference. I am making the change now but weirdly, I still cannot parse using the getElementsByTagNameNS method.

Comment: @heyya99 - You need to make sure the local name parameter does not have the prefix `foo` and not `ns:foo`.  Also it will only work if you had called `setNamespaceAware(true)` on the `DocumentBuilderFactory` that was used to build/parse the document.

Comment: That suggestion worked. I will get it deployed. Can you tell me if the ordering of xmlns:xsi and xsi:type in the XML document would have any impact. I see they are in different orders in the parse-able and non-parse-able xml.

Comment: I am working on a large legacy application. If I use setNamespaceAware(true) and use getElementsByTagNameNS  for the code that fails to parse, will this have an impact on the rest of my application? Do I have to replace every getElementsByTagName with getElementsByTagNameNS?

Comment: I have tried the getElementsByTagNameNS idea and it has not fixed the issue. I am still unable to parse some XML.